# Why doesn't Python support numeric constant?

Tags: python, constants

For instance, in C++, a numeric constant can be defined as "**const** int NAME_MAXLEN = 10;" I don't think there is an equivalence in Python. Why is that?

Comment: A related question: [Why no 'const' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291791/why-no-const-in-python)

Comment: The answers to these sorts of questions are always going to boil down to "because that's what the designers of the language decided to do".